# How can receive emails in Java based system preferably with spring?

Tags: java, spring, email, imap, pop3

I have looked up Google and Spring documentation but can not find any thing on receiving emails.

I need to build a client (kind of not fully blown client) that can receive emails from POP3 and IMAP. I am already using Spring in the project so preference is Spring.

Lots of links point to James but while it does look like a good project does not provide enough documentation and I am not even sure it does what I am after i.e just a small client that is able to to receive emails.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Spring integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/mail.html#mail-inbound) was designed to solve these kind of problems. In particular it has [e-mail receiving adapters](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/mail.html#mail-inbound). Here is an IMAP example from the documentation:

```
<mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
      store-uri="imaps://[username]:[password]@imap.gmail.com/INBOX"
      java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
      channel="recieveChannel"
      should-delete-messages="true"
      should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
      auto-startup="true">
      <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="5000"/>
</mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 2):

POP3 and IMAP are not protocols that *receive* email. They go out and *fetch* it from a server.

The official [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)

> provides a platform-independent and protocol-independent framework to build mail and messaging applications.

Take a look!