# Spring integration with mail

Tags: spring, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

Am doing a POC on receiving mail via Spring Integration. I configured my configurations by using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9109585/1423818) But my POC is throwing an exception.
My pom file looks like this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I am getting following exception when i try to run the program.

```
    DEBUG: Exception loading provider, THROW: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at javax.mail.Session.getService(Session.java:788)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:586)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:548)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openSession(AbstractMailReceiver.java:207)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:225)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:111)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:214)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:184)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
01:04:31.034 WARN  [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter] error occurred in idle task
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: imaps
```

i tried to change the sun mail api versions and javax mail api versions to 1.4.4 but no use could any one please guide me what extra or version of jars am i required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>imap</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

As you see I fix some versions, remove redundant transitive deps and add required.

Comment: Thanks that worked but facing another issue. I am try ing to connect to out look but my domain name is different. It is giving following exception.
     `DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect returning false, host=xxxxxx.co.in, user=mallikarjun_d, password=<null>
19:42:56.725 WARN  [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter] error occurred in idle task
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified `

Comment: Sorry, but it is a different question. So, just start it and I'll help you. And let's close this one, if it has been fixed already!